# How to detect name collision error with Active Record in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I defined `enum` like this.

```
enum order_quota: {plenty: 0, limited: 1, none: 2}
```

Then I got this error.

> ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "order_quota" on the model "Product", but this will generate a class method "none", which is already defined by Active Record.

I understand the error is caused by name collision with a Active Record class method.

The problem is that the error is raised only in production mode.
Which config should I change to detect the error in development mode?

Comment: It seems you can't unless you invoke the `order_quotas` method that Rails creates when using enums. In that case a couple of tests would cover the name collision problem.

Comment: Any test that even loads the class would have caught it. The reason it raises in production is class eager loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do to test this enum is reference the class so that it is evaluated. When you have no automated tests things blow up in production. That's as constant as death and taxes.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "it does not blow up" 
    Product
    assert true
  end
end
```

The reason an error is raised on start-up in production and not in development is the [`config.eager_load`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) setting which loads all your models on startup. And no - you don't want to set it to true in in development to catch this error as it will mess up code reloading.